# Pretty-print or re-indent lighttpd.conf?

Tags: lighttpd

Is there a tool which will pretty-print or re-indent lighttpd's `lighttpd.conf`?

I'm using Vim, but <kbd>VG=</kbd> (Vim's reindent-the-whole-file command) goes haywire.